# Async/await doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, promise

I wrote this code based on my understanding of Async/await and how it works. Basically i want my `run()` function to wait for `captcha` value to be set by clicking button and `set_captcha` function and then run the rest of the code

```
var captcha = false ;

function get_captcha() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve , reject ) {
    if(captcha === false ){
      reject(captcha );
    } else {
      resolve(captcha);
    }
  });
}

async function run() {
  var captcha = await get_captcha();
  console.log( ' captcha confirm -> ' + captcha );
}

run().then(function(){ console.log('done')});

function set_captcha(){
  captcha = 123;
}

</script>
<button type="button" onclick="set_captcha();">captcha</button>
```

but obviously Im missing something. When I run the code I get this error in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) false
```

and when I click the button and call `set_captcha()`  nothing happens.

Comment: That's not how `async/await` (or Promises) works.  You are running the code before you are setting `captcha` to a different value. You'd have to call `run` or `get_captcha` again from your click event handler. `async/await` just provides a convenient way to deal with promises so that you can do `var foo = await bar();` instead of `bar().then(foo => ...)`. That's all.

Comment: The callback you pass to the Promise constructor is immediately called. It's not called again after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about async/await more like syntactic sugar that uses promises.

If the function is `async` it means it always return promise. That is the reason why you can await only in `async` method - as it always remains in a promise chain, it can return you the value inside async function - However when you return something out of that function, its always promise again.

Same as promises - once you are inside promise chain, you cant get value "outside of promiseChain" (like you can save it to some global variable, but you cannot return value directly from the chain - you can return only promise that can be resolved with a value).

You can rewrite any async function to promise chains and vice versa

This function:

```
async function run() {
    var captcha = await get_captcha();
    console.log( ' captcha confirm -> ' + captcha );
}
```

is equal to this one:

```
function run() {
    return get_captcha().then(captcha => {
       console.log( ' captcha confirm -> ' + captcha );
    });
}
```

---

The error: At beginning, captcha is false, therefore you reject promise at `if(captcha === false )  reject(captcha );` with value false and you do not catch it, which ends with `Uncaught (in promise) false`

Comment: This doesn't explain the error `Uncaught (in promise) false` mentioned in the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 - ah true, missed that, added to answer